# Getting 401 unauthorized exception while importing Powershell Reports

Tags: powershell

I am getting `401 unauthorized exception` while downloading(Excel/CSV) Powershell Reports.
I have tried by adding `/-/script/handle` in `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting but no luck.

**Sitecore Version:** Sitercore 9.1

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Joy

[image]

Answer (score 7):

We had the same issue and solution was to enable `Spe.IdentityServer.config` at `\inetpub\wwwroot\website\App_Config\Include\Spe`.

OOTB this file comes with Sitecore Powershell module as disabled. Just need to remove `.disabled` from the config name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem in `Sitecore version 10.3`, and I found a solution. To resolve this issue, please add the provided line of configuration to the `siteNeutralPaths` node in the specified path.

In the path `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\<instance name>\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config`, add the line:

```
<path hint="spe">/sitecore%20modules/PowerShell</path>
```

.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs in Sitecore 9.1+ instances.

---

Solution:-  Add below mentioned line to allow powershell to download/upload files like export excel/csv etc.

## File Name:- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config

Please confirm what needs to be added to the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config for this issue

Comment: I've already uploaded image and shared link for the solution. Please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhtNT.jpg

Comment: There is actually a configuration file included with SPE 5.1+ which patches the appropriate setting for Identity Server support.